# Meaning of Japanese slang phrase「モロです」?

Tags: meaning, slang, definitions, internet-slang

Can somebody provide a explanation of the meaning of the term モロ as used in the phrase 「モロです」?  I see references describing もろ/モロ as an adverb meaning "completely" or "totally" but that doesn't seem to be the sense of the word being used here.

Example sentences gleaned from the web:

1) 「先生! モロです！」 (in reference to an element of a drawing that is mildly scurrilous and presumably is unacceptable)

2) 「いきなり異動にモロです！」

From the above, I infer that the meaning is something similar to ダメ or いけない but it would be nice to have a more solid definition.  My thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Is the 2nd example from [this page](http://muscleboyschoolrecords.com/pastcolumn1504.html)? Is so, the
 モロ is the name of a member of [the band "Clamatone(クラマトーン)"](http://muscleboyschoolrecords.com/bands.html), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This もろ comes from もろに and it means "directly" or "head-on."
It's a slangy word. More contexts are needed to tell what these example もろ are supposed to mean. But the first one sounds like the drawing is exposing something which is not supposed to be exposed ("*directly* exposed").

Comment: Thanks for your contribution!  As mentioned in the question, I'm aware of the もろに adverbial sense, and that does not appear to be the way in which モロ is being used here.  I'm not quite sure if 「Xがもろにです。」 would even be grammatically valid (though I certainly could be mistaken and would welcome a correction).

Comment: You can construe もろにです as 「もろに(○○した)」です. I guess this phrase was contracted even more and もろです have got to be used commonly.