# Meaning of モロ in boxing

Tags: meaning, words, slang, katakana, sports

An ex boxer punches a man and then says:

> おっと… 勢い余ってとどめ入れちまった。生きてる?

The man that was punched manages to stand up. At this point, a friend of the puncher says:

> マジか…　所沢さんの**モロ**もらって…

I think that the sentence roughly translates as `"Unbelievable... he is still standing after receiving a punch by Tokorozawa..."`, but I can't understand the exact meaning of モロ. Does it have a special meaning in boxing? Or it simply indicates a punch given with all one's strength?
I know there's [another question about モロ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47369/meaning-of-japanese-slang-phrase-%E3%83%A2%E3%83%AD%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99), but in that case it is used as an adverb, while here I think it is used as a noun. Thank you for your help!

Comment: A correct answer has already been posted, so I will say this here.  「モロ」 is an adverb here as well that modifies the verb 「もらって」.   The noun, which is the object of the verb, is 「所沢さんの」 with the 「の」 as the nominalizer.   = "所沢's punch(es)"   You would need to "see" or "feel" an imaginary 「を」 between 「所沢さんの」 and 「モロ」.  Mentally filling in the words left unsaid is an important part of Japanese reading comprehension.   Failure to do so would often result in not understanding a phrase or sentence.

Comment: @l'électeur Thank you for your advice! I "felt" an imaginary を, but I placed it after モロ. I didn't understand that the word 'punch' has been left unsaid.

Comment: モロ is one of the [adverbs where に is optional](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/41536/5010) (especially in casual speech).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from the question you linked applies to your question as well.

So to put it into the translation, it means the boxer took a direct, unguarded hit.